# First hitting time of biased random walk in 2 dimensions

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, random-walk, stopping-times

I am trying to find the distribution of first hitting times of a 2D biased random walk to reach a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I found the answer for the 1D case of brownian motion here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model but there are no references and no work to get to that result. I would like suggestions about how to do it for my case or references on this matter.

The formula I would like to find should be similar to the one for the 1D case

$f(t)\equiv\frac{|x_c-x_0|}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt^3}} \exp\left(- \frac{(x_c-x_0)^2}{4Dt}\right)$

Comment: What set of points are you hitting? I.e. can you define your stopping time precisely?

Comment: Its a line. In my original problem I want to find the distribution of the walk starting at (0,0) to hit x = constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B_t = (B_t^x, B_t^y)$ be a 2-dimensional Brownian motion. In particular $B_t^x$ and $B_t^y$ are independent $1$-dimensional Brownian motions. Define the first hitting time of the line $L_{x_0} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, : \,x=x_0 \}$ by $$\tau = \inf\{ t>0 \, : \, B_t \in L_c\} = \inf\{ t>0 \, : \, B_t^x = x_0\}$$
From the one-dimensional result it follows that
$$f_\tau(t)\equiv\frac{|x_c-x_0|}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt^3}} \exp\left(- \frac{(x_c-x_0)^2}{4Dt}\right)$$

Comment: What is the procedure to get the 1D result? I could not find the way to derive it or a source that have it. Usually the derivation I found is the time to return to origin

Comment: @dguerrero Suppose $\tau_c$ is the first hitting time of level $c$. Then $P(\tau_c > t) = P(\sup_{0\leq s \leq t} B_s < c) $, where this last probability is given by the [reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process))